# Как в Python с помочью BS4 вытащить из тега текст исключая вложенные теги?

Tags: python, парсер, bs4

необходимо вытащить текст который находится внутри тега

при этом игнорируя содержимое вложенных тегов  и  и записать полученные данные в одну переменную?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
    <div itemprop="articleBody">
    <p align="center"><strong>Заголовок</strong></p>
    <p><strong>еще текст</strong></p>
    <p>Бла бла</p>
    <p>Бла бла бла</p>
    <p><img src="../01.jpg"/></p>
    <p><img src="../02.jpg"/></p> 
    </div>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
tag = soup.find("div", itemprop="articleBody")
tag.strong.decompose()
tag.img.decompose()
print(tag.text)
```

decompose() удаляет по одному элементу, но количество элементов таких элементов может меняться.

Еще пробовал сделать так, но не получается запихнуть результат в одну переменную

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
tag = soup.find("div", itemprop="articleBody")
for el in tag:
    try:
        tag.strong.decompose()
        tag.img.decompose()
    except:
        pass

    print(el.text)
```

Comment: покажите ожидаемый вывод для вашего примера

Comment: спасибо, уже разобрался

Answer (score 0):

Получилось сделать так

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
tag = soup.find("div", itemprop="articleBody")
for el in tag:
    # print(el)
    try:
        tag.strong.decompose()
        tag.img.decompose()
    except:
        pass
    # print(el)
    names = [str(i.text) for i in tag]
print(names)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
html = '''
    <div itemprop="articleBody">
    <p align="center"><strong>Заголовок</strong></p>
    <p><strong>еще текст</strong></p>
    <p>Бла бла</p>
    <p>Бла бла бла</p>
    <p><img src="../01.jpg"/></p>
    <p><img src="../02.jpg"/></p> 
    </div>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
tag = soup.find("div", itemprop="articleBody")
names = list(tag.strings)
print(names)
names = list(tag.stripped_strings)
print(names)

['\n', 'Заголовок', '\n', 'еще текст', '\n', 'Бла бла', '\n', 'Бла бла бла', '\n', '\n', '\n']
['Заголовок', 'еще текст', 'Бла бла', 'Бла бла бла']
```